# putExtra does not work and crashes

Tags: android, string, android-activity

I'm calling Activity with this action on button click:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codice);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Firma.class);
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

//the text.getText in this case is "ASDFASD" I have tested with simple toast

Now call the "codice" from new activity `onCreate` with:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();            
Log.e("codice", intent.getStringExtra("codice"));
```

but the app crash this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException`: println needs a message

and if not use a Log.e and make a toast with codice the toast is empty.

Comment: you should use it like `text.getText().toString`

Comment: Update: I missed () at the end, it should be `text.getText().toString()`

Comment: Yes your problem is text.getText().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add **`toString()`**

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks so much, first comment =)

Comment: @J.DoeCd According to SO rule, You should accept this answer.

Comment: Now is 4 minutes =)

Answer (score 3):

Add [**`toString()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object.

```
getText().toString()
```

**Finally**

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

> change this **text.getText()** line to:

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText());
```

> to **text.getText().toString()**

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText());
```

With:

```
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codice);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Firma.class);
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Try this I  hope it work

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most appropriate way to do this

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codice);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Firma.class);
intent.putExtra("codice", text.getText().toString().trim());
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then in your second activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getExtras() != null) 
{
    String str = intent.getExtra("codice");
    Log.e("codice", intent.getStringExtra("codice"));
}
```

Comment: add `toString()` please.